# Android webview screenshot in case of hardware acceleration

Tags: android, webview, hardware-acceleration

I want to get a screenshot of webview，and code show as follow:

`View view = myWebView;
Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
view.draw(canvas);`

It doesn‘t works under hardware acceleration(webView or activity set), when i turn off hardware acceleration, I can get a normal screenshot, otherwise it is a white screen。

test url is : http://cdn.codeboy.me/canvas.html

and then screen before hardware acceleration turn on:
[image]

and after hardware acceleration turn on:
[image]

Is any way to get webView's screenshot under hardware acceleration(just webView and not window or decorView), and anybody can explain why it doesn't work when turn on hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue. My solution is using MediaProjection API to capture full screen image, then crop the image to get WebView's screenshot.

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide an example of how to use the API.