# Android webview to bitmap but hardware accelerated

Tags: android, webview, hardware-acceleration

**TL;DR:** What is the hardware accelerated replacement of this code?

```
        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1280, 720, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        myWebView.layout(0, 0, 1280, 720);

        myWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        myWebView.buildDrawingCache();

        canvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
        myWebView.draw(canvas);
```

#### Detail:

I am trying to get webView content to unity. I am using int array to do that job. I succeeded with `webView.draw`. Don't worry about onCreate function. I know it is so messy.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        myWebView = new WebView(this);
        wcc = new WebChromeClient() {};
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(wcc);
        //setContentView(myWebView);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(myWebView, true);

        myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 1, 0));

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                }
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(webview, url, favicon);
                webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {

                webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onPageFinished(webview, url);

            }
        });
        myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");


        myWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null); //HARDWARE

        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED); //HARDWARE

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/QouNHuTnypQ");

        System.loadLibrary("NativeCameraPlugin");
        nativeInit();

        setContext(this);

        _renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);

        _handlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG);
        _handlerThread.start();

        //startCamera();

    }
```

. And this function is requested from unity. I took the code from a camera plugin for unity. And trying to bypass my webView image. This function loops in unity thread.: https://github.com/robsondepaula/unity-android-native-camera

```
private void requestJavaRendering(int texturePointer) {

        //Log.e("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "Heyyyooooo");
        if (!_update) {
            return;
        }

        int[] imageBuffer = new int[0];

        if (myWebView != null) {
            imageBuffer = screenshot(myWebView); // this is the where webView converted to bitmap
        }

        if (imageBuffer.length > 1) {
            GLES30.glBindTexture(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturePointer);

            GLES30.glTexSubImage2D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1280,
                    720, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    IntBuffer.wrap(imageBuffer));

        }
    }
```

But problem is when I try to use with html5 content (like embedded youtube video) everything works nice even audio plays but the video is black. I have tried those solutions:

#### Trying 1: `webView.draw`

I have used the way everyone use. But like I said it is not rendering the video. Just audio plays and some video pause, mute, settings etc. shows up.

```
 public int[] screenshot(final WebView webView) {
        try {
            myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1280, 720, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            myWebView.layout(0, 0, 1280, 720);

            myWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            myWebView.buildDrawingCache();

            canvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
            myWebView.draw(canvas);

            IntBuffer intBuf = bitmapToRgba(myBitmap);
            int[] intArray = new int[intBuf.remaining()];
            intBuf.get(intArray);
            //isDone = false;

            return intArray;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

After some search I saw Canvas doesn't support hardware rendering. I tried to enable `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in activity and application section of androidManifest. Also tried to enable on Unity side. Even tried to enable from everywhere that possible (you can see the onCreate function.). But it didn't work. It returns everytime false when I call `canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()`.

#### Trying 2: VirtualDisplay

So I tried display method. But I couldn't get it work. Image returns null. And also I don't know where should I put that code.

```
ir = ImageReader.newInstance(1280, 720, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 4);

        DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
        VirtualDisplay vd = dm.createVirtualDisplay("Test Display",
                1280, 720,
                DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT, ir.getSurface(), DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRESENTATION);

        Presentation presentation = new Presentation(myWebView.getContext(), vd.getDisplay());
        presentation.show()

        Image img = ir.acquireLatestImage();
        Image.Plane[] planes = img.getPlanes();
        buff = planes[0].getBuffer().asIntBuffer();
```

I came accross Presentation and VirtualDisplay with those links but they don't have detailed explanation:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/android_webview/docs/software_draw_deprecated.md

[Android webview screenshot in case of hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341455/android-webview-screenshot-in-case-of-hardware-acceleration)

Those links have detailed explanation but I don't know how to apply to code:

[Android WebView with layer_type_software not showing HTML5 canvas content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57465334/android-webview-with-layer-type-software-not-showing-html5-canvas-content)

https://medium.com/bolt-labs/how-to-programmatically-capture-screen-on-android-a-comprehensive-guide-f500c95e455a

.

Also I can't do `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`. If I do that, video doesn't render even I do `setContentView(myWebView)`.